# R package pROC always reports AUC > 0.5

Tags: r, roc

Both

```
pROC::auc(0:1, 1:0)
pROC::auc(0:1, 0:1)
```

give an AUC of 1..

With more experiments, it seems that it always returns max(AUC, 1 - AUC).
Is there an option to change this?
I can't find a GitHub repo to report this issue.

Comment: Not a bug as pointed out in the answers, but for future reference, here is the github repo: https://github.com/xrobin/pROC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `pROC::roc` there is an argument `direction` which is by default set to `auto`.
From the documentation of `roc`:

> direction - in which direction to make the comparison? “auto” (default):
>   automatically define in which group the median is higher and take the
>   direction accordingly. “>”: if the predictor values for the control
>   group are higher than the values of the case group (controls > t >=
>   cases). “<”: if the predictor values for the control group are lower
>   or equal than the values of the case group (controls < t <= cases).

```
pROC::auc(0:1, 1:0, direction = "<")
pROC::auc(0:1, 0:1,  direction = "<")
```

An explanation of such rationale is given in the comments by Calimo: There is no reason to assume that higher predictor values are more positive in all cases. As in the case of a model indicating the probability of the negative class

More on the matter can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756682/what-does-coercing-the-direction-argument-input-in-roc-function-package-proc)

Comment: Auto doesn't make any sense. If your prediction is wrong, it should stay as well. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The rationale originally was not so much "worse than random", but that there is no reason to assume that higher predictor values are more positive in all cases. I have seen plenty of cases where higher values indicate a negative outcome. Think of a model indicating the probability of the negative class.

Comment: @Calimo this is indeed correct, my explanation was obscured by the fact that I always setup the data in way that `1` is the class with the higher probability in binary classification (or at least this is sought from the model). Also I wish to thank you for `pROC`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the auc function in ModelMetrics:

```
ModelMetrics::auc(0:1, 1:0)
ModelMetrics::auc(0:1, 0:1)
```

Output:

```
[1] 0
[1] 1
```

Comment: This seems to be a great package, and super fast. Thanks!